# How to resolve compilation terminated error in C++ when I use <atomic>?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

I am running below C++ code in ubuntu virtualbox and receiving the error mentioned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <cinttypes>
int main () {
   std::atomic<uint64_t> x = 123456;
  // printf("%u\n",force->atomic_load());
   //printf("%u\n",force);
   printf("x = %" PRIu64 "\n", x.load());

   return(0);
}
```

ERROR:

```
root@abano:/home/ashna# vim abc.c
root@abano:/home/ashna# gcc abc.c -o abc
abc.c:4:18: fatal error: atomic: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: You are compiling in C language. Use C++ instead.

Comment: The `gcc` front-end program is for building C files. The source file you show is C++ for which you need to use the `g++` command (and a different file suffix, `.c` is for C source files, use e.g. `.cpp` instead).

Comment: I m using gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12)

Comment: Try: `mv abc.c abc.cpp` `;` `g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic abc.cpp -o abc`

Comment: ... and use C++ header files instead of C header files. `cstdio`, `cstdlib`, `cstdint`.... Also prefer streaming instead of using `printf`. `#include <iostream>` instead of `stdio.h` and `std::cout << x.load(); << '\n';`

Comment: I'm also voting to close this as a "typo" kind of problem...